# Is babel-cli plus presets all I need to compile ES6 to ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is it sufficient to only install the so-called 'babel-cli' locally plus presets (es2015, react etc.) in the project-folder to compile ES6-code?

**That's all?**

I can remember that there is another model 'babel' which has to be installed globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Babel (i.e. babel-cli) locally or globally, it's your choice. The Babel authors recommend local installation, quote from the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/):

> While you can install Babel CLI globally on your machine, it’s much
>   better to install it locally project by project.
>
> There are two primary reasons for this.
>
> 1. Different projects on the same machine can depend on different
>      versions of Babel allowing you to update one at a time.
> 2. It means you
>      do not have an implicit dependency on the environment you are working
>      in. Making your project far more portable and easier to setup.

So the answer to your question would be: **Yes, that's all.**